# make does not find X11 library (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, compiling

I'm trying to run the make command to install the supermongo package:

https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/sm/sm.html

but I get this error:

```
In file included from x11.c:20:0:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44:10: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/X.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'x11.o' failed
```

I've already installed all the required libraries, among which `libx11-dev`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

(From the command `apt-file search /X.h`)

The package you're missing is **x11proto-dev**.

Comment: Turns out I already have x11proto-dev :(

Comment: @garpez - does the file **/usr/include/X11/X.h** exist? If so, then maybe your program is looking for it in another place. On your version of Ubuntu, it doesn't exist anywhere else.

Comment: yes, the file does exist. How do I know the program is looking elsewhere for it?

Comment: I'm thinking that the x11.c file needs to use the full path to X.h. Find the #include line and change it to **#include </usr/include/X11/Xlib.h>**. If that doesn't work, you'll need to contact the devs.

Comment: sadly, it didn't work :(